# How to press and hold in Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, ios-simulator

I’m developing a flutter app using vs code and the Xcode simulator and I want to test a function where I have to press and hold. It’s not working how can I test it?

I tried the shift and left click but it didn’t work. I also tried to connect my iphone but it also didn’t work because of the certification.

Answer (score 1):

Check the **Trackpad** settings on the Mac:

[image: Screenshot]

With the settings shown here, a `LongPressGesture` works for me when I hold using three fingers. It also works to "force click" the trackpad with one finger and then hold. I haven't tried it wuth Flutter though.

Comment: Every long press with your mouse on the simulator is a long press. How do you navigate on you simulator, the standard way is the cursor of your mouse / trackpad

Comment: @AndroDevs Is that a question? Yes, I navigate with the trackpad, I don't have a mouse.

Comment: Thanks when I fixed the settings it worked.